# Does a facebook photo url always stay the same?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting photos from facebook through graph api with this call:

https://graph.facebook.com/[AlbumID]/photos

The links I get there for the - do they stay the same or do they change?

I am interested because I like to cache these links, but if they get updated, eg the CDN does some updates or reorganisations, then there would be issues.
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CDN URLs can change. You are better off caching the graph URL with the respective object ID, for example,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305/picture
```

Comment: yes, I agree. Storing the CDN URL would make the CDN useless... Thanks.

Comment: any suggestions on what we can / should cache in order to show images without having to repeatedly request all photo data from facebook?